# Django model automatically set fields

Tags: django, custom-fields

I have a form allowing users to post an article. The article table is chained with the users table so, I need to set the user_id field based on who's writing. Normally, django form will display a drop down to allow me to select the author but that's not the case for the user.

```
I have the following code:

if request.method == 'POST':
    ArticleForm = ArticleForm( request.POST )
    if ArticleForm.is_valid():
        article = ArticleForm.save ()
        return render( request, 'success.html' )
else:
    ArticleForm = ArticleForm()

return render( request, 'post.html', {'ArticleForm': ArticleForm} )
```

How do I set a field before validating the request which will fail in case not since certain fields are supposed to be set by the code and not based on request data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are making sure the user is signed in.

models.py:

```
Article(models.Model):
    text = modesl.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

forms.py:

```
ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        exclude = ('user',)
```

views.py:

```
article = Article(user=request.user)   

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ArticleForm(request.POST, instance=article)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponse('success')
else:
    form = ArticleForm(instance=article)
```

Another way to set data before saving is to use:

```
if form.is_valid():
    art = form.save(commit=False)
    art.user = request.user
    art.save()
    return HttpResponse('Success')
```

Comment: comming from PHP I think the last method attracts me most. Dunno why. I will accept your answer, thanks.